# Visual Studio 2019 Xamarin Forms Google Ads - Build Problem

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, admob

I have had an issue for weeks after upgrading to the latest VS2019 and XF versions. Along the way, I have moved from VS 16.3.2 to .5 with no fix. It displays "Unexpected Element  found in  - AndroidManifest.xml - Line 14. I have also updated many of the NuGet packages and performed clean/build many times. Any ideas?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.linkemupllc.NYWineryHopper" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionName="release-2.01.02" android:versionCode="20102">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.LOCATION_HARDWARE" />
  <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" android:xlargeScreens="true" />
  <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
  <application android:label="NYWineryHopper.Android" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication" android:allowBackup="true" android:debuggable="true">
    <activity android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="NYWineryHopper" android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:name="md5c4b3563624aac5beb34a83ad25365fc4.MainActivity">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name="md5dcb6eccdc824e0677ffae8ccdde42930.KeepAliveService" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Battery Broadcast Receiver" android:name="md5d630c3d3bfb5f5558520331566132d97.BatteryBroadcastReceiver" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Energy Saver Broadcast Receiver" android:name="md5d630c3d3bfb5f5558520331566132d97.EnergySaverBroadcastReceiver" />
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:label="Essentials Connectivity Broadcast Receiver" android:name="md5d630c3d3bfb5f5558520331566132d97.ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver" />
    <provider android:authorities="com.linkemupllc.NYWineryHopper.fileProvider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true" android:name="xamarin.essentials.fileProvider">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/xamarin_essentials_fileprovider_file_paths" />
    </provider>
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="false" android:name="md51558244f76c53b6aeda52c8a337f2c37.PowerSaveModeBroadcastReceiver" />
    <provider android:name="mono.android.MultiDexLoader" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="1999999999" android:authorities="com.linkemupllc.NYWineryHopper.mono.android.MultiDexLoader.__mono_init__" />
    <provider android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="1999999998" android:authorities="com.linkemupllc.NYWineryHopper.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__" />
    <!--suppress ExportedReceiver-->
    <receiver android:name="mono.android.Seppuku">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="mono.android.intent.action.SEPPUKU" />
        <category android:name="mono.android.intent.category.SEPPUKU.com.linkemupllc.NYWineryHopper" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <!-- Include the AdActivity and InAppPurchaseActivity configChanges and themes. -->
    <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" android:exported="false" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
    <provider android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider" android:authorities="com.linkemupllc.NYWineryHopper.mobileadsinitprovider" android:exported="false" android:initOrder="100" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
  </application>
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: VS is updated to .5 and Xamarin is at ver 16.3.0.426, All NuGet packages have been updated. I have tried moving the activity inside of application, but each build moves it back. What can I do to force it to stay in the proper place?

Comment: you said that you have issue after updating to the latest vs 2019 and XF version, so the google ads ca display successfully before?

Comment: Yes, things were working perfectly with VS2019 previous versions. Compiled, built and distributed NC Wine Hopper and VA Wine Hopper for both Android and iOS. A similar issue was previously solved with a Visual Studio update, so the only solution may be to wait on MS.

Comment: Previous similar problem was with 16.1.2 and the update to 16.1.3 fixed it, although that was an iOS problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56541022/xamarin-forms-ios-admobviewrenderer-vs2019

Comment: yes, maybe you need to wait on MS, but you can also create thread about this issue on github, MS will see this feedback, then to fix this issue.

Comment: Updated VS to 16.3.6 and XF to 16.3.0.246 but no fix. I have filed issue #8163 on Github

Comment: I have posted the issue on Github and someone on there keeps telling me to move the line and manually add it. I sure hope that somebody at MS will take it seriously and fix the build process.